# can't add data to firebasedatabse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just discovered firebase and wanted to test wether I could use it as a database for my android app. I think i'm sending data to it but on the firebase console it shows nada. I tried everything to fix it by myself but seems I lack the knowledge. Please enlighten me :(

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseI;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseD;
    private String uMail;

    EditText userMail; // textbox where i write data to be sent to databse


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        userMail = findViewById(R.id.mail); 
        mFirebaseI = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseD = mFirebaseI.getReference("DataUsers");
        uMail=mFirebaseD.push().getKey();

    }

    public void addUser(String mail)
    {
        DataBaseData users = new DataBaseData(mail); //class i made with just one string attribute
        mFirebaseD.child("Users").child(uMail).setValue(users);
    }

    public void send(){
        addUser(userMail.getText().toString().trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. Doing this will also conveniently automatically highlight the Android code in your question.

Comment: You're not calling `addUser` or `send` from anywhere, so that could be an explanation. Another reason might be due to your `DataBaseData` class, so you could try just doing `.setValue(true)`. And a third common reason could be that the security rules for your database don't allow the writes. If that last one if the case, you'll find an error message in the logcat output of your app.

Comment: send method is the onClick in my layout so i'm calling it when I click the button. for the rest i checked and everything's ok... 
thanks anyways :)

Comment: "everything's ok" is not very actionably here. Was there an error message in your log about permissions? Did the behavior change when you use `.setValue(true)`?

Comment: No change at all. I rebuilt it about 2 minutes ago and now i get an error saying it couldn't find the `send(view)`method in a parent or ancestor Context. 
I'm trying to find out what that is as i'm writing this.

Comment: Have you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I learned that realtime database is "outdated" and that firestore is way better and easier to use. And it is! So what I did to add just a single "name" to "users" collection is this :

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    //private String uMail;

    EditText userMail;
    Button btnSend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.send);
        userMail = findViewById(R.id.mail);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();



        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                String username = userMail.getText().toString(); //pseudo a save dans la bdd

                Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>(); //hashmap obligatoire pour utiliser firestore

                userMap.put("name", username); // suavegarder le pseudo dans la bdd sous le nom de document "name"

                mFirestore.collection("users").add(userMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Toast.makeText(home.this, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        String error = e.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(home.this, "failed:" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

I think it's pretty simple so I didn't add any comments for you guys I mean if I understand it then anyone can haha! anyways thanks for trying to help me out!